# Where can I find a finite element analysis library for the .NET platform?

Tags: .net, winforms, finite-element-analysis

I could use a library that implements the Finite Element Method in my winforms application. Is there available any such library for the .NET platform?

Comment: Ip's from tmarouda and ileon are unfortunately the same.
To sum up Anaxsoft has been very slow and most of antispam modules report it as a spam app.
Furthermore it does not support non linear analysis.

Comment: Can't understand why anybody would care whether FEA runs on .NET or not.   Feels like a guarantee that it'll be slow.   I'd go with an industry leader: ANSYS, MSC, ABAQUS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know, there's only one company that provides .NET software for finite element analysis. Visit [Anaxsoft](http://www.anaxsoft.com/) (www.anaxsoft.com). They provide a finite element analysis SDK for the .NET Framework.

Comment: how much the price of anaxsoft license ?

Comment: the website does not such a thing at the time I checked!

Answer (score 2):

I've found these finite element packages for .net from internet.

Not open source (some have free editions):

- [EngiSSol 3D frame analysis](http://www.engissol.com/3d-frame-library.html)
- [SolverBlaze Finite Element Library](http://www.cg-inc.com/cgiSolverBlaze.aspx)
- [AnaxSoft FEEA SDK](http://www.anaxsoft.com/contents/products/feeasdk/Default.aspx)

Open sources:

- [MGroup FE](https://github.com/mgroupntua/FEM)
- [BriefFiniteElement.NET](https://github.com/BriefFiniteElementNet/BriefFiniteElement.Net/)
- [feaserver](https://code.google.com/p/feaserver/)
- [#FE](https://github.com/iainsproat/SharpFE)

Comment: Just spent a few hours trying to use BriefFiniteElement.NET and it is far from complete. Doesn't even have triangle or tetrehedron elements fully emplemented.

Comment: @Eric Does any of the above software support tension only/ compression only features?. Please refer below question. This is a major blocker for us. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63133140/python-package-library-for-linear-non-linear-3d-structural-engineering-finite

Comment: I've been digging around about this quite a bit and even though it costs, I'm going with Inventor Nastran. I'm still investigating but I believe you can run it from the command line, and you would be able to edit the input files to your heart's content using python.

If you want to know all the details: MSC Nastran is a tier 1 aerospace grade solver, and is prohibitively expensive. That said, they were declared a monopoly in 2005 or so and had to give up their source. I believe Inventor NASTRAN is based off of that source but I'm not 100% sure of that.

Comment: solverBlaze library https://www.cg-inc.com/Product/SolverBlaze

Answer (score 0):

Engineering Software Solutions offers a great library for .net with numerous advantages over anaxsoft library. We have been using engissol's libraries for 2 years without any problem and are very happy especially when solving geometrically non linear problems (second oreder theory). On the other hand, anaxosft library had some bugs preventing the integration to our c# application interface.

Comment: We downloaded both Anaxsoft's SDK and engissol's libraries. Engisool works only for really small structures and we found some problems with dynamic analysis (errors). On the other hand, we verified all of our examples/test cases with FEEA SDK without errors. Integration problems with Anaxsoft's SDK? Very smooth integration, superior licensing system and technical documentation.

Comment: You guys sound like competitors.  Any chance you could disclose your affiliations?